# Can I make the compiler optimize function calls in structs?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, optimization, module

When I write code I try to keep the logically divisible parts of a program separate by creating "modules". It's really easy coming from languages like Javascript with NodeJS or Python to accomplish this. With C I've found ways to accomplish this with a pattern I've provided an example of below. I use static method declarations with `const` declared structs to create "modules" to organize my code.

I've noticed that the cost of calling a method with this technique is usually just one assembly instruction per invocation.

Instead of

```
movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
movl    %edx, %esi
movl    %eax, %edi
call    my_add_method
```

the "module" technique will generate

```
movl    $my_add_method, %ecx
movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
movl    %edx, %esi
movl    %eax, %edi
call    *%rcx
```

What I want to find is a way of declaring these modules but have the compiled output be identical to just calling the method by it's immediate name.

What I would like to know is:

1. Is there a way to have the compiler (gcc), either with flags or by declaring the structures differently, optimize the code so that the resulting asm is the same?
2. I imagined this would be *simple* thing for a compiler to optimize, if no method exists, why is this kind of optimization generally not possible? (considering the structures are all constant and static)

---

```
/**
* File: main.c
* Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
* Compile: gcc main.c -S -o main
*/
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int (* const add_func)(int, int);
} MY_MOD_T;

static int my_add_method(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

const MY_MOD_T Module = {
    .add_func = my_add_method
};

int main(void) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;

    // substitute these two lines to see the different output like above
    int result = Module.add_func(a, b);
    //int result = my_add_method(a, b);

    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you reliably detect the performance difference?

Comment: Have you tried using the optimization flag (-O)? The output will be very different. Trying to optimize asm output in `-O0` is probably an exercise in futility.

Comment: No. This isn't a performance concern, just a curiosity. I just thought this would be a simple thing for a compiler to optimize.

Comment: If you turn on optimization you can do even better than what you're asking, the compiler can inline the function: https://godbolt.org/g/yPUI8f

Comment: I didn't try it for my at-home example but yes, it does work on this example and they output identical. I'll have to try it on a larger project written with that technique with more variations.

Comment: I'm not sure this "module" approach is useful. It seems to me like you'd expose yourself to all kinds of initialization order disasters.

Comment: @KerrekSB This is C code, so initialization order isn't an issue.

Comment: This kind of thing is useful for plugins, where several may be loaded that each use their own versions of the same set of functions... but otherwise, why not just name the functions with a prefix for their module instead of sticking them all in a struct (so instead of `Module.add_func(a,b)` you'd use `Module_add_func(a,b)`)?

Comment: @Dmitri it's mostly a style preference, coming from higher-level languages it's just pleasant to see dot-notation used to access methods and constants :)

Comment: If you really *want* member functions for structs, you should try C++.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, it is not possible to make a function call through a function pointer behave identically to calling a named function.

In your example, consider a header file `module_interface.h`:

```
typedef struct {
    int (* const add_func)(int, int);
} MY_MOD_T;
```

A different header file called `module_derived.h`:

```
#include "module_interface.h"

extern const MY_MOD_T Module;
```

An implementation for the derived module in `module_derived.c`:

```
#include "module_derived.h"

static int my_add_method(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

const MY_MOD_T Module = {
    .add_func = my_add_method
};

int module_add_method(int a, int b) {
    return my_add_method(a, b);
}
```

Then, your main program would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "module_derived.h"

extern int module_add_method(int a, int b);

int main(void) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;

    // substitute these two lines to see the different output like above
    int result = Module.add_func(a, b);
    //int result = module_add_method(a, b);

    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, result);
    return 0;
}
```

If `module_derived` is actually a shared library, there really isn't an optimization level that can help overcome the fact that the function pointer value has to be dereferenced. At `-O3`:

<kbd>`# Calling named function`

        `movl    $6, %esi`

        `movl    $5, %edi`

        `call    module_add_method`</kbd>

 
        <kbd>`# Calling through module`

        `movl    $6, %esi`

        `movl    $5, %edi`

        `call    *Module(%rip)`</kbd>

As you can see, there is an extra offset computation and a dereference when going through your module mechanism.

For shared libraries, though, this module overhead is comparable to the overhead imposed by position independent code (the PLT and GOT overhead). So, in practice, the overhead is not worth worrying about, unless profiling tells you otherwise. In that case, you would have to consider finding a way to inline the hot function calls.

Comment: Using ```-shared``` does explain why I've been seeing the different outputs even when -O is being used, thank you!